# Understanding simple Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a program where I can input a function, odd and even for example, and it would give me everything that **doesn't** apply to that function. Say, separate odd [1,2,3,4] - this should return [2,4] and [1,3] if we ran the function even. Below is what I have written:

```
separate f (x:xs)
  | f x = filter f xs
  | otherwise = x : filter f xs
```

Why does this occur as shown below? It appears that if f x is true, it will filter the rest and ignore x, otherwise, it will take x and filter the rest using the same guidelines. Am I missing something here?

```
separate odd [1,2,3,4]
=> [3]
```

Comment: You want this to return a tuple of two lists? Note how you aren't adding to any list in the first case in the guard.

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of the observed output? `odd 1` is `True` so your function will output `filter odd [2,3,4]`, which is `[3]`

Comment: @carcigenicate Ideally, I would like to return a list within a list, a new sublist each time f x is true. I thought that excluding the addition to the list in the first guard would allow me to remove anything where f x is true, which is what was desired

Comment: @kirency You might want to take a step back and try a simpler function first to get a good grasp of recursion and list iteration. Try writing your own versions of `map` and `filter` and `foldl`.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond that makes sense. How then can I continue to filter the rest of the list at each case of f x being true if I do not add anything to my list because I want to ignore anything where f z is true? Thanks!

Comment: @carcigenicate will do, thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you're trying to do. What do you want the output of `separate odd [1,2,3,4]` to be? Note that, as @Carcigenicate, if you want to return 2 lists the return type needs to be a tuple.

Comment: @robin zigmond I would want to return [[2],[4]]]. Thanks for your patience! I didn't know it needed to be in tuple form, that may be why!

Comment: Oh hang on, I think I misread your OP. Do you want to return just a single list, of the elements that *don't* satisfy `f`? (That would be `[2,4]` here, not a nested list.) In that case you just want `separate f = filter (not . f)`

Comment: @RobinZigmond that was my OP, yes. I was actually trying to do so with a nested list eventually, however. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your two cases, you call `filter`; you almost certainly intended to (recursively) call `separate` instead.

```
separate f (x:xs)
  | f x = separate f xs
  | otherwise = x : separate f xs
```

This will get you to the next bug.

Comment: Thank you so much - exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @kirency if the answer worked for you, you have to accept it.